# Laravel как запустить скрипт чтобы он работал без браузера

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет! Мне нужно запустить скрипт на сервере с Laravel который бы был запущен все время, что то вроде forever -c php php-file.php но чтобы я имел доступ к моделям и контроллерам из Laravel.

я использую github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets, на нем сделал чат итд, но беда в том что это игра (график растет и падает), и мне нужно чтобы это все работало даже когда никого на сайте нет

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan - это не то, что вы ищите?

Comment: @РустамГимранов к сожалению нет, мне нужно чтобы скрипт был запущен все время

Comment: Какой скрипт, для чего, его суть, запустить и дальше что с ним делать? Какой смысл держать скрипт запущенным без браузера если просто посылая запрос на указанный url можно получить ответ, я вижу смысл запускать скрипт только в том случае, если нужно создать сокет, но тут побольше в vuejs идет /node.js / redis. Сайт по-сути запущен и работает, смысл его запускать навсегда? Чтобы вам быстрее ответили, вы должны максимально подробно описать вопрос

Comment: Самое простое решение которое приходит в голову создайте job и перезапускайте ее в `handle`. Но как правильно заметили выше - нужно более подробноописать задачу.

Comment: @MoloF именно! для сокетов, простите просто не знаю как лучше описать, я использую https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets, на нем сделал чат итд, но беда в том что это игра (график растет и падает), и мне нужно чтобы это все работало даже когда никого на сайте нет

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов спасибо, сейчас изучаю в документации, выше более подробно описал

Comment: Ну вы так и не написали, что должен делать скрипт, который будет работать в цикле. Пока я думаю что вариант с job вам подойдет. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#creating-jobs

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов вызвать Events для  графика на websocket  и работа с бд. То что вы сказали, очень похоже на то что нужно, но не могу найти как запустить его в background, из консоли, чтобы он срабатывал не в определенный момент (когда пользователь вошел итд),а чтобы он вызывался один раз и работал постоянно

Comment: Используй supervisor на серваке, в документации про очереди очень хорошо описано, как настроить демон очереди, примени к своему случаю

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
php artisan make:command DispatchJob
```

to create special artisan command that runs jobs.

Open created DispatchJob.php file and define DispatchJob class like this:

```
class DispatchJob extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'job:dispatch {job}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Dispatch job';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $class = '\\App\\Jobs\\' . $this->argument('job');
        dispatch(new $class());
    }
}
```

Now you should start queue worker:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

and after that you can run jobs from command line:

```
php artisan job:dispatch YourJobNameHere
```